# Is matrix $W^{T}*H^{T} = H*W$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to calculate non-negative matrix factorization. If I replace $W$ with $H^T$ and $H$ with $W^{T}$, will I get the correct result?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-ask-a-good-question for information on how to attract quality answers. Proper formatting is expected; for information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $(HW)^T = W^TH^T$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the identity $(AB)^T = B^TA^T$

Hence: $W^T*H^T = (HW)^T$

Now, if $HW$ is symmetric, this means $(HW)^T = HW$, the result follows. Otherwise, there is not an equality.

So, in general, both will not be equal.